# How do you fix a shower handle bar

Tags: repair, shower

After pulling too hard on this bar, the plastic fitting/washer-type thingy broke off. The right side still has it (picture #2). The bar is now very loose and will come all the way out.

Shower repair kits on Amazon seem to have nothing to offer in this area. And I don't even know how to locate a model number or brand on a shower.

I'd be fine if it looked crappy. I just want it not to leak water into that hole. Ideally I could fix it like new, but if I just had to plug up both sides that would be acceptable. I just don't know how to go about any of that.

[image]
[image]

Comment: that looks like a shaver, not a shower handle bar

Answer (score 1):

Take the measurements of the internal and external diameters and turn 2 up on a lathe, if you don’t have one or access to one then any local machinist can do it.

They can make them with “ears” or tabs so they will clip into place.

Comment: If you can take out the good one, just take that to a machinist and have them replicate a pair. I recommend replacing both because if one broke, the other probably isn't that much better.

Answer (score 1):

If one is unable to locate a shop that will fabricate a set of sleeves, another option is to locate a makerspace or a maker who will fabricate via 3D printing. Same suggestion as Solar Mike, a split design that snaps together will make things easier.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely will look poor, though looking better than poor is an option - caulk it in place with silicone or polyurethane caulk. DIY "rubber rings," once cured.